# How to publish Gradle project to Azure Artifacts?

Tags: java, azure, gradle, azure-artifacts

I am trying to publish a jar into Azure Artifacts using the command: `./gradlew publish`. I am not running into any error. Gradle is making it look successful, even the stacktrace, looks like the publish command succeeded. But when I open Azure artifacts feed, there is nothing that connected to the feed. I also tried `./gradlew publishAllPublicationsToMyFeedRepository` with the same result.
Take the comments as multiple combinations of attempts I tried to get this to work:

build.gradle:

```
    plugins { 
        id 'java-library' apply true
        id "net.linguica.maven-settings" version "0.5" apply true
        id 'maven-publish' apply true
    }
    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2'
    }
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes('Main-Class': 'com.myapp.LanguageApp.SayHello')
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        // maven {
        //     credentials {
        //      // I replaced the username with a PAT name, and password with PAT token
        //             username "username"
        //             password "password"
        //     }
        //     url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/username/azure-artifacts/_packaging/MyFeed/maven/v1'
        //     name 'MyFeed'
        //     authentication {
        //         basic(BasicAuthentication)
        //     }
        // }
    }
    publishing {
        publications {}
        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/username/azure-artifacts/_packaging/MyFeed/maven/v1'
                name 'MyFeed'
                // authentication {
                //     basic(BasicAuthentication)
                // }
                credentials {
                // I replaced the username with a PAT name, and password with PAT token
                    username "username"
                    password "password"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'gradle-project'
```

~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>MyFeed</id>
      /// yes, I replaced the username with a PAT name, and password with PAT token
      <username>username</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will answer my own question. I was missing the group and version in the build.gradle. So gradle was actually successful in publishing my artifacts, it just needed the group and version to identify the specific artifact.

```
group: thegroup
version: theversion
```

Comment: Please mark your answer to your own question as correct.